# Guzzle response issue

Tags: php, guzzle6

I'm sending URL to remote server using Guzzle 6. If I try to send same URL with Postman, I will receive back generated report...which means that URL and connection is fine. Every time I dd file_put_contents, I will receive false. If I put some random string instead for $response, everything works. Executing my code will give me 200 OK, but as said I will always receive false with dd.

```
$this->client = new Client();
    $response = $this->client->post($url);

    dd(file_put_contents($this->filename, $response));
```

Comment: try `$response->getBody()`

Comment: file_put_contents($this->filename, $response->getBody())

This works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$response` alone will not work as this is an object.

You'll need to use `$response()->getBody()` to get the contents of the response.

It may also be worth casting it as a string: `dd(file_put_contents($this->filename, (string)$response->getBody()));`